# How do I load a page and populate some fields after httpRequest (ajax call) and some verification? After clicking signin redirect and populate field

Tags: javascript, ajax

Assistance is required as I am relatively new to this.

I am having difficulty populating fields on a second page after clicking a button.

**For instance:**

- one clicks the sign-in,
- information is verified,
- if successful a new page is loaded then some fields get populated.
- The data is retrieved from a database,
- once the information is verified the page redirects to another page then fields on the newly loaded page get populated with the information,

**However, this is not working for me.** I do understand that **after loading the new page subsequent scripts won't run.**

```js
function makeRequest() {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if (!httpRequest) {
    alert("Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance");
    return false;
  }

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
  httpRequest.open("GET", queryUrl2, true);
  httpRequest.send();
}

function displayContents() {
  // let email = $("#uname").val().trim();
  // let password = $("#pword").val().trim();
  if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
      console.log("Perfect!");
      console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
      let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
      let verifyEmail = jsonResponse["email"];
      let verifyPhone = jsonResponse["phoneNumber"];

      if (email === verifyEmail && password === JSON.stringify(verifyPhone)) {
        hold.push(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse["phoneNumber"]));
        console.log(hold[0]);
        console.log("pushed");
        window.location.replace("../index.html");
      } else {
        alert(
          `Invalid Username and/or Password. Please confirm and try again.`
        );
        window.location.href = "/";
        console.log(`error: there was a problem`);
      }
    }
  }
}

makeRequest();

window.onload = function windowLoad(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(window).ready(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setValue(hold[0]);
      console.log(`This is the lost hold variable: ${hold}`);
    }, 1000);
  });
};

let setValue = (x) => {
  x = x;
  console.log(x);
  $("#sphone-1").text(x);
  $("#phone-1").val(x);
  $("#phone-2").focus();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the data locally.

*sign-in page:*

```
hold.push(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse["phoneNumber"]))
storeLocal(hold)

function storeLocal(data){
    localStorage.setItem('userData', data);
}
```

*index.html page:*

```
window.onload = () => {
    let userData = getLocal()
    console.log(`This is the found hold variable: ${userData}`);
    setValue(userData[0]);
}
function getLocal(){
    localStorage.getItem('userData');
}
```

Looking at the flow of data in your code, it seems you are retrieving the user credentials from the server and checking if they are valid on the client. This **isn't good practice**, as authentication and user credentials should be handled on the backend. The client should securely send their username and password to the server and the server should send back and encrypted token that the user will store locally and use to retrieve user data from the server in the future.

*sign-in*

```
async function submit(username, password){
    const params = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    }
    const response = await fetch('api/user', params)
    if (response.ok) {
        const jwt = await response.json()
        localStorage.setItem('token', jwt);
        window.location.replace("../index.html");
    } else {
         // invalid credentials 
    }
}
```

*index.html*

```
window.onload = async () => {
    let userData = await getData()
    setValue(userData[0]);
}
async function getData(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const params = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
    }
    const response = await fetch('api/user', params)
    if (response.ok) {
        const userData = await response.json()
        return userData
    } else if (response.status === 401) { 
        // unauthorized
        clearSession()
    }
    function clearSession () { localStorage.removeItem('token') }
}
```